# Surface integrals help?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble understanding visually how a surface integral works/calculates. For a standard double integral, function $f(x,y)$ and a rectangular region $U=[a,b]\times[c,d]$ then the double integral: $$\iint_{U}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{a}^{b}dx\int_{c}^{d}dy f(x,y)$$ simply calculates the volume underneath the graph $f$. My problem now is when you aren't integrating over a flat region of space but a curved surface $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$. Now I can't visualize this as a volume below the graph $f$ as there is another restraint.

However someone explained surface integrals in this way to me. Imagine I am calculating the mass of a sheet of metal represented as a surface $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$, with a function $f(x,y,z)$ defining its density at any point. In this case the mass will be obtained by integrating the density-function over the surface.

i.e I am still finding the surface area of the surface but multiplying that area by its value of $f(x,y,z)$ at every point. So if I want to find the surface area itself, I use $f(x,y,z)=1$. This would be consistent with my description of volume in the standard flat space integral as I'm simply multiplying the area $(U)$ by the height at that individual point $(f(x,y))$.

Now I'm wondering whether for the curved space model whether the volume is actually the space between the two graphs if plotted on the same axis.

> So my question is this. Do my ideas make any sense? Also you have any ideas on how I can visualize these integrals please share them? It really helps my problem solving when I can physically visualize the problem in my head.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, your ideas do make sense.

Long answer: I see that the only conflict you have is about visualizing volume between 2 curved surfaces as a double integral.

For 2 surfaces represented by $u=f(x,y)$ and $v=g(x,y)$, the volume of the space between them on a region $R$ can be represented as:
\begin{equation} V=\iint_{R} |\ u-v\ |\  dxdy \end{equation}

Now, all that remains is the sense of region $R$ in the terms of one of the surfaces itself. I see that as just a transformation of the coordinates, albeit a non linear one.

Does that answer your question?